# Как разобраться с выводом объекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `объект` в котором будут отзывы, порядка `200 шт`, их нужно фильтровать по номеру телефона и выводить на экран (в отзыве картинки, ссылки текста...)
С фильтрацией по номеру телефона я разобрался, вопрос с выводом

1. Как можно при загрузке выводить определенное кол-во отзывов, например 9 (сейчас вывожу все) и дальше по клику на кнопку подгружать остальные (например по 3)
2. Схожая ситуация после фильтрования, например после фильтрации получилось 50 нужных отзывов, а мне сразу нужно вывести только 9, а остальные по клику на кнопку подгружать

P.S. после фильтрации перед выводом я собираю блоки в скрытый `div` (мне кажется это не лучшее решение)

https://jsfiddle.net/hmdL1742/1/

```js
// Отзывы
const reviews = {
  "+7 (000) 000-00-00": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>',
    "social_network": "INSTAGRAM",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (111) 111-11-11": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 1",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>',
    "social_network": "FACEBOOK",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (222) 222-22-22": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 2",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>',
    "social_network": "ВКОНТАКТЕ",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (333) 333-33-33": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 3",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>',
    "social_network": "INSTAGRAM",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (444) 444-44-44": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 4",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>',
    "social_network": "FACEBOOK",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (555) 555-55-55": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 5",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>',
    "social_network": "INSTAGRAM",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (666) 666-66-66": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 6",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>',
    "social_network": "ВКОНТАКТЕ",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (777) 777-77-77": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 7",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>',
    "social_network": "INSTAGRAM",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (888) 888-88-88": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 8",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>',
    "social_network": "FACEBOOK",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
  "+7 (999) 999-99-99": {
    "name": "Снежанна Ноготок 9",
    "img_src": "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "social_link": "https://vk.com/",
    "social_icon": '<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>',
    "social_network": "ВКОНТАКТЕ",
    "title": "Спасибо вам за работу",
    "text": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget,      tempor sit "
  },
};

// строка ввода запроса
const searchReview = $('#searchReview');
// сюда добавляем отзывы
const revOutput = $('#reviews')
let rev = ''

// Шаблон отзыва
let reviewTemplate = `<div class="block">
 <div class="card">
  <img class="{{ img_class }}" src="{{ img_src }}" alt="{{ img_alt }}" class="avatar">
  <p class="name">{{ rev_name }}</p>
  <a class="link" href="{{ social_link }}" target="_blank">
    {{ social_icon }}
      <span>{{ social_network }}</span>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="text">
  <p class="title">{{ title }}</p>
  <p class="rev_text">{{ text }}</p>
 </div>
</div>`;

// Плейсхолдер в поле поиска
(function typingInSearchField() {
  $('div.search').on('focus', function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() === $(this).attr('title').trim()) {
      $(this).html('');
    }
  }).on('blur', function() {
    if ($(this).text().length < 1) {
      $(this).html($(this).attr('title'));

      if ($(this).hasClass('searchCatalog')) {
        initCatalog();
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('searchReview')) {
        initReviews();
      }
    }
  })
}());


// Первый вывод отзывов
function initReviews() {
  $('.hid_reviews').html('');
  rev = '';

  for (let phone in reviews) {
    if (typeof reviews[phone] !== 'undefined' || reviews[phone] !== null) {
      rev += reviewTemplate
        .replace("{{ rev_name }}", reviews[phone]["name"])
        .replace("{{ img_class }}", reviews[phone]["img_class"])
        .replace("{{ img_alt }}", reviews[phone]["imgAlt"])
        .replace("{{ title }}", reviews[phone]["title"])
        .replace("{{ text }}", reviews[phone]["text"])
        .replace("{{ social_link }}", reviews[phone]["social_link"] ? reviews[phone]["social_link"] : '')
        .replace("{{ social_icon }}", reviews[phone]["social_icon"] ? reviews[phone]["social_icon"] : '<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>')
        .replace("{{ social_network }}", reviews[phone]["social_network"] ? reviews[phone]["social_network"] : 'ВКОНТАКТЕ')
        .replace("{{ img_src }}", reviews[phone]["img_src"]);

      // Сбор блоков перед выводом
      $('.hid_reviews').html(rev);
    }
  }
  // Вывод блоков
  $(revOutput).html($('.hid_reviews').html());
  $('.hid_reviews').html('');
};
initReviews()


// Ввод в поле поиска и рендер Отзывов
$(searchReview).on('input change keydown', function() {

  const v = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gim, '');
  if (v.length < 2) return;

  $('.hid_catalog').html('');
  let t = '';

  // Регулярка для удаления символов кроме цифр
  //str.replace(/[^0-9]/gim,'')

  for (let phone in reviews) {
    if (!!~phone.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, '').indexOf(v)) {

      t += reviewTemplate
        .replace("{{ rev_name }}", reviews[phone]["name"])
        .replace("{{ img_class }}", reviews[phone]["img_class"])
        .replace("{{ img_alt }}", reviews[phone]["imgAlt"])
        .replace("{{ title }}", reviews[phone]["title"])
        .replace("{{ text }}", reviews[phone]["text"])
        .replace("{{ social_link }}", reviews[phone]["social_link"] ? reviews[phone]["social_link"] : '')
        .replace("{{ social_icon }}", reviews[phone]["social_icon"] ? reviews[phone]["social_icon"] : '<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>')
        .replace("{{ social_network }}", reviews[phone]["social_network"] ? reviews[phone]["social_network"] : 'ВКОНТАКТЕ')
        .replace("{{ img_src }}", reviews[phone]["img_src"]);

      // Сбор блоков перед выводом
      $('.hid_reviews').html(t);
    }
  }
  // Вывод блоков
  $(revOutput).html($('.hid_reviews').html());
});
```

```css
.search {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  box-shadow: 6px 10px 5px 1px rgba(1, 1, 1, .1);
  border: 1px solid #f1b80b;
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 70px;
  padding: 16px 10px;
}

#reviews {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#reviews,
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  width: 360px;
  border: 2px solid #ffb900;
  padding: 20px 70px 20px 15px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block .card {
  width: 90px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 10px 8px 8px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px 5px rgba(1, 1, 1, .07);
  top: -45px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.block .card img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.block .card .name {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.block .card .link {
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.block .card .link i {
  color: #ffb900;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.block .card .link span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.block .text {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.block .title {
  color: #ffb900;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.block .rev_text {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="search searchReview" id="searchReview" title="Напишите номер сотового телефона подрядчика, что бы посмотреть отзывы">
  Напишите номер сотового телефона подрядчика, что бы посмотреть отзывы
</div>

<!-- Сюда грузятся отзывы -->
<div id="reviews"></div>

<!-- По клику хочу подгружать новые блоки -->
<a href="#x" class="btn">ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЕ</a>

<!-- Здесь собираю блоки перед вставкой -->
<div class="hid_reviews" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: чтобы не выводить полностью список нужно заменить цикл который бежит по всем элементам, на цикл который бежит только по 9 нужным

Comment: а потом как? делать счётчик, запоминать номер на котором остановился, и когда нужно будет подгружать новые отзывы пройти циклом до последнего загруженного элемента и вывести след. 3 и запомнить новое число в счетчик?

Comment: запомнить номер последнего выведенного например и выводить начиная с него.

Comment: альтернативный вариант - сразу сгруппировать список по 9 элементов и идти в цикле уже по этом новому списку.